# Creating a Collapsible table in JSP

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, hashmap

JSP Code:

```
 <c:forEach var="map" items="${map}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table border="1">
                                <tr class="header expand">
                                    <th>${map.key.id}</th><th>${map.key.name}</th><th>${map.key.status}<span class="sign"></span></th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                            <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
                            <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
                            <th>PRICE</th>
                            <th>STATUS</th>
                        </tr>
                                <c:forEach var="item" items="${map.value}">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td><td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td><td>${item.PRICE}</td><td>${item.STATUS}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

Collapsible Table Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr.header
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.header .sign:after{
  content:"+";
  display:inline-block;      
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content:"-";
 }
</style>
<body>
<table border="0">
  <tr  class="header expand">
      <th colspan="2">Header <span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.header').click(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
  </script>
</body>
```

I have a map which is being retrieved in JSP. It has object as key and arraylist as values.The arraylist consists of rows as objects.For a particular key which has unique reqid,it has all rows specific to the reqid as objects in the arraylist. I want to retrieve it in JSP. It must be collapsible table in such a way that key is my header and values i.e rows related to reqid must be present under that header.I have independent JavaScript code to implement it.I tried adding up in JSP but there is no outcome on browser.I need help in designing collapsible table in JSP code.

Expected Output:

```
123  A   1   ///Table header 
123 A   5  2
123 A  10  3
//N no of rows 

456 B 2    ///Table header 
456 B  20  3
456 B  25  2
//N no of rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jquery code is working but `structure` of your table is wrong .There are many `invalid` elements in it. That's the reason jquery is not able to find `correct` element to expand or collapse.

Some of the changes you need to make in your table structure :

```
<table>
  <c:forEach var="map" items="${map}">
  <!--no need to have new tr td here that just add extra row to your table-->
    <tr class="header expand">
      <th>${map.key.id}</th>
      <th>${map.key.name}</th>
      <th>${map.key.status}</th>
      <th><span class="sign"></span></th>
    </tr>
   <!--no need to have different table-->
    <tr>
      <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
      <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
      <th>PRICE</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${map.value}">
      <tr>
        <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td>
        <td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td>
        <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
        <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Here is the **demo code** for above table structure:

```js
$('.header').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

.header .sign:after {
  content: "-";
  display: inline-block;
}

.header.expand .sign:after {
  content: "+";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="header expand">
    <th>${map.key.id}</th>
    <th>${map.key.name}</th>
    <th>${map.key.status}</th>
    <th><span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none" >
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td>
    <td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="header expand">
    <th>${map.key.id}</th>
    <th>${map.key.name}</th>
    <th>${map.key.status}</th>
    <th><span class="sign"></span></th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <th>REQUEST_ID</th>
    <th>LOGIN_USER</th>
    <th>PRICE</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
  </tr>

  <tr style="display:none">
    <td>${item.REQUEST_ID}</td>
    <td>${item.LOGIN_USER}</td>
    <td>${item.PRICE}</td>
    <td>${item.STATUS}</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I am getting one error:Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toggleClass(...).nextUntil is not a function
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (file.js:9)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.handle (jquery.min.js:19)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:19)

Comment: did you add jquery cdn ? in your code ? i.e : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head></head> ` tag

Comment: The error is just rectified.Thanks for the help.I just need small update in the code.How can we keep toggle off by default initially?That is when user clicks on + it need to show up the rows

Comment: It completes the requirement.But when page loads for the first time,it shows all content of a table for microsecond and then hides.So is there a way to get through this? You can actually view by running your demo code.

Comment: use `style="display:none"` for trs  which you don't want to show .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215105/discussion-between-beginner-and-swati).